# Putting Mata Shodasi Mahavidya picture with other gods and recite mantras

Tags: mantras, rituals, tantra, shakti, dasha-mahavidya

Can **Mata Shodasi** **Mahavidya** picture be put in pooja room with other gods?
I don't know anything about **MahaVidya** but want to do Mata Shadoshi puja. Is there any special rule to do her puja and if not done properly, Will there be any side effect? Also can a girl chant her mantra?

Comment: It is not recommended to do pooja of Tantric deity without initiation. But you can still do bhakti puja to her.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto i dont what happend to my reputation they have decreased from 20 to 13 now i am not able to join in chat since a week.... I tried geting some badges but reputation didn't increase... May be now i cant talk woth u guys anymore...

Comment: You need to gain reputation by asking right questions and answers. Looks like some found your questions not useful and downvoted.  For the least you can work on gaining rep by editing question or answer posts(Only if you found the posts need any corrections like Grammar or formatting). For each correct edit you would earn +2 reputation. :) Once you reaches to 20 rep, you can again be able to chat in chatroom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sri Vidya mantras (particularly the Shodashi or Shodakshari mantra) are the most secretive among all mantras. So, the rule is to recite only after getting initiated from a Guru of that Parampara (of Sri Vidya).

Swami Shivananda, advises to recite a lot mantras in his book "Japa Yoga - A comprehensive treatise on Mantra Sastra ", but for Sri Vidya mantras, he specifically points out the need for initiation.

> Sri-Vidya is the great Mantra of Tripurasundari or Bhuvanesvari or
> Mahamaya. It is also called the Panchadasi or the Panchadasakshari,
> for it is formed of fifteen letters. In its developed form it consists
> of sixteen letters and is called Shodasi or the Shodasakshari. **The
> aspirant should directly get initiation of this Mantra from a Guru,
> and should not start reading it for himself or doing Japa of it, of
> his own accord. This is a very powerful Mantra and, when it is not
> properly repeated, it may harm the Upasaka. So it is imperative that
> it should be got directly from a Guru who has got Siddhi of this
> Mantra.**

And, there is no problem with being a woman and chanting the mantras of Sri Vidya. According to Tantras, [everyone, including women has the right to be initiated](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23248/4732). One of the Gurus of this particular Sri Vidya Paramapara is Lopamudra, the wife of Agastya Muni.

So, the real problem is to chant the mantras without getting initiated first.Being a woman is not a problem.

And, once you are initiated by a Guru, you will be taught the proper methods of doing a formal worship. Till then you can do a devotional worship, by offering lightened incense, lighted lamps, flowers etc. to the image. Place the image on an altar (covered with a red cloth) in your Puja place and while worshipping make sure to face either the East or the North.